# "No session currently bound to execution context" in unit test with DropWizard Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, dropwizard

I'm using DW with Hibernate, and trying to write a unit test for my DAO. I've based my code off [this example](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/1310d7c981581b4e1be97104f5bb34c3a8e68ee9/dropwizard-hibernate/src/test/java/io/dropwizard/hibernate/UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactoryTest.java). Unfortunately, `getCurrentSession()` always throws, even immediately after a call to`sessionFactory.openSession()`:

```
sessionFactory.openSession();
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); 
// throws org.hibernate.HibernateException: No session currently bound to execution context
```

My `setUp` is almost identical to theirs (except for the JDBC driver and URL). Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong? Do I need to set `current_session_context_class` perhaps, and if so, how? I'm not using a configuration file. Maybe I should be?

I suppose I could create my `SessionFactory` more [like this](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/6fcfe910ec2e3491fe66bc0263334de8489c71b7/dropwizard-testing/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/testing/common/DAOTest.java#L98), but that's not the DropWizard way I think.