# Calling method 'createQuery' is not valid without an active transaction

Tags: hibernate, dropwizard

I'm using DropWizard and Hibernate. I build my `SessionFactory` like this:

```
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.setProperty(AvailableSettings.DRIVER, "org.h2.Driver");
        configuration.setProperty(AvailableSettings.USER, "");
        configuration.setProperty(AvailableSettings.PASS, "");
        configuration.setProperty(AvailableSettings.URL, "jdbc:h2:file:./var/test");
        configuration.setProperty(AvailableSettings.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        configuration.setProperty(AvailableSettings.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "thread");
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory();
```

(See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63292887/no-session-currently-bound-to-execution-context-in-unit-test-with-dropwizard-h) if you're wondering why.)

The first of these `createQuery` calls succeeds, and the second fails (with the error in the title):

```
        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.createQuery(...).executeUpdate();
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(...).executeUpdate();
            transaction.commit();
        }
```

Are the two sessions *supposed* to be different, or is that an artifact of how I've set things up? The reason I want the second version to work is that it's actually being called from a different class that only has a handle to the factory. Should I be passing around sessions?

Comment: Do you use the `@UnitOfWork` annotation in the respective resource method? Could you share a bit more code i.e. where do you open the session and how does your resource method look like etc.?

Comment: @philonous Sorry, I should have indicated that this is a JUnit test for the DAO (per the question I linked).

Comment: You shouldn't need to setup your session factory the way you do. See the section about Hibernate in the docs: https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/testing.html – are you using Dropwizard 2?

Comment: @philonous Thanks! Somehow I missed that section. But even after using that technique, I have the same problem. The only thing that has changed is the error message: "javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query" (again, only the `getCurrentSession` version causes this).

Comment: I guess the right way to do this is to use the `database.inTransaction` pattern. I'll see if I can make that work for me. Would be nice if the above pattern worked too though!

Comment: @philonous I'm able to make `inTransaction` work, but since it's not connecting to my (test) H2 db, I can't test things like uniqueness constraints in my SQL. Do you know if there's a way to use Hibernate with my H2 in tests?

Comment: Can you share your whole test class? Or maybe even a repository?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've shared a simplified version of the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63457714/why-does-my-jql-query-return-a-different-result-than-the-equivalent-criteriabuil

Comment: I meant thanks for your _help_