# Why does my JQL query return a different result than the equivalent CriteriaBuilder query?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, dropwizard

I'm using Dropwizard Hibernate and am having issues with my tests. I've simplified this example as much as possible. I create a `Foo`, update it, and then try to fetch it. Using a raw query gets the correct result, but the equivalent CriteriaBuilder query doesn't catch the update. What am I doing wrong?

```
    @Test
    public void testFoo() {
        String id = "12345";

        // Create
        Foo foo = Foo.builder()
            .id(id)
            .name("old-name")
            .build();
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().replicate(foo, ReplicationMode.EXCEPTION);

        // Update
        database.inTransaction(() -> {
            CriteriaBuilder cb = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaUpdate<Foo> update = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(Foo.class);
            Root<Foo> root = update.from(Foo.class);

            update.set(Foo_.name, "new-name");
            update.where(cb.equal(root.get(Foo_.id), id));
            int updated = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(update).executeUpdate();
        });

        // Select
        database.inTransaction(() -> {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush(); // Not sure if this matters

            String newName = (String) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("select name from Foo where id=:id")
                .setParameter("id", id)
                .getSingleResult();

            assertEquals("new-name", newName);
            log.error("New name is " + newName);

            CriteriaBuilder cb = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Foo> cq = cb.createQuery(Foo.class);
            Root<Foo> root = cq.from(Foo.class);
            cq.where(cb.equal(root.get(Foo_.id), id));
            Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(cq);

            Foo foo2 = (Foo) query.getSingleResult();
            log.error("New name is " + foo2.getName()); // Prints "old-name"
        });
    }
```

Here's my setup code:

```
@ExtendWith(DropwizardExtensionsSupport.class)
public class UpdateTest {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public DAOTestExtension database = DAOTestExtension.newBuilder()
        .addEntityClass(Foo.class)
        .build();

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        sessionFactory = database.getSessionFactory();
    }
...
}
```

I can also show the `Foo` class, but it's not very interesting.

Comment: What is Foo_.id ? is the underscore a typo?

Comment: @Guillaume It's called a static metamodel: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html. Foo._id is equivalent to "id" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Foo` instance is still in the L1 cache i.e. the current session which is not touched by the update statement. Since Hibernate/JPA has to retain identity for entity objects of a session, it can't clear the session due to the update statement. Usually, one has to clear the session or refresh instances after an update statement to reflect the current state again.

Try doing `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().clear();` instead at the start of your read transaction

Comment: Thanks, that worked! So updates within the session (either through a raw query, or through `CriteriaBuilder`) will not be reflected in later queries unless I `clear()`? Is it a common pattern to `clear()` before every query, then? Are you familiar with any resources that explain all this in depth? (A quick Google search turned up lots of half-baked articles.)

Comment: Sorry if my last comment wasn't clear. I've tried doing the update using `CriteriaUpdate`, expecting that it would touch the cache (see updated code). But I get the same result. Is this expected? If so, I'm confused about how the cache is supposed to work!

Comment: The problem is that JPQL/SQL DML statements do not affect the entity objects directly in the L1 cache. If you query entities after doing a DML, Hibernate will rightfully retain object identity and instead of loading the state from the query result, will just return you the object from the L1 cache if available. If you do DML statements, you should clear the session if you want to query entities with the same session. Note that this is usually no problem because sessions are lightweight and should be short-lived i.e. only for one transaction.

Comment: Thanks Christian, but I'm *not* doing DML updates anywhere, am I? I assume you saw my last comment?

Comment: A ha, thank you! Apparently I was confused about what constitutes a DML statement. If I call session.update() directly, it works as expected. Many thanks!